# Understanding 2 Trevs

Tags: british-english, slang, understanding, irish-english

the passage is from Jerusalem by Jez Butterworth. What 2 Trevs stand for?

GINGER. I’m a DJ.

JOHNNY. He’s an unemployed plasterer.

PROFESSOR. I see. Are you pure or applied?

GINGER ( to the PROFESSOR) . Just a tick, mate. ( To
JOHNNY . ) Since, right, I’m pencilled in second if 2 Trevs
pulls out today, from the car park of The Cooper’s at sunset.
I got my records in the car. ( To the PROFESSOR . ) Sorry.
You were saying.

PROFESSOR. A DJ, eh?

GINGER. That’s right, mate.

In another part:

GINGER. I fucking am. Possibly. I’m standby DJ at The
Cooper’s.

WESLEY. Are you?

GINGER. Yes I fucking am. I spoke to Sue.

WESLEY. She never said nothing. When?

GINGER. Last week. I’m back-up for 2 Trevs. If the 2 Trevs
can’t make it, or, say, one or both of the Trevs is ill.

WESLEY. I just spoke to them, they’re fine. They’re on their
way.

GINGER. Right. But, what if they, you know…
LEE. Get lost?

DAVEY. Crash?

LEE. Have a fight. Musical differences.

GINGER. Or food poisoning. One of them could eat a dodgy
burger.

LEE. They’re called 2 Trevs. There’s two Trevs. So if one
Trev eats a dodgy burger. There’s a spare Trev.

Comment: "2 Trevs" is probably the name that another DJ is known by, the same way that Bruce Morrow of WABC-770 NYC in the 1970s was known as "Cousin Brucie".

Comment: Presumably an act consisting of two men called Trevor.

Comment: @KateBunting - Yes, that's more likely; my original comment was posted before the querent added the "In another part:..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Trev" is a common shortening for the name "Trevor". It's an anglicised spelling of a Welsh name.

> They’re called 2 Trevs. **There’s two Trevs**. So if one Trev eats a dodgy burger. There’s a spare Trev.

So there is an act called '2 Trevs' comprising of two men both called Trevor.

Speaking as a British native, certain shortened names are synonymous (rightly or wrongly) with working-class people. Unlike widely accepted shortened names like 'Tom' (Thomas), 'John' (Jonathan) or 'Frank' (Francis) which can sometimes be used as given names anyway, shortenings like 'Daz' (Darren), 'Kev' (Kevin), 'Trev'(Trevor) and 'Dave'(David) are viewed more as 'nicknames', the kind used by close friends in very informal settings. This may have been in the mind of the writer when characterising the "two Trevs".

Comment: I agree, except that _John_ and _Jonathan_ (note spelling) are separate names with their origins in the Bible. The latter may be abbreviated to _Jon_ (without an 'h').

Comment: @KateBunting Yes, I believe I mentioned that they can all be names in their own right. But some people called Johnathan *do* shorten it to 'John'.

Comment: It just seemed odd to refer to one of the commonest male names in the English language  as a shortened name which 'can sometimes' be used as a given name. I will accept that the non-traditional spelling _Johnathan_ could be abbreviated thus.

Comment: I've never seen 'Johnathan' spelled like that.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey It is an Americanism, apparently an amalgamation of the usual spelling of 'Jonathan' and 'John'. My point is that some people who are named Jonathan (any spelling) go by the name 'John' (or 'Jon') and they may use it professionally. It is not considered informal or a 'nickname'.